# Symfony2 routing choice

Tags: symfony, dynamic, routes, locale

I'm new to symfony, but thinking about starting a project.
I have one requirement, I need dynamic routes with multilingual support
http://example.com/locale/category/category_1/category_2/.../category_N/item, 
As it can be guessed, each of those categories will have list of child categories.
Also when switching language, it should automatically switch all categories, and item to that language
So the routes would be very similar of those wordpress or joomla cms have.
As far as I can tell I have few options: 
1. Use locale setting and symfony default routing with "/" enabled, 
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html
2. Use symfony cmf router, thought din't had enough time to fully grasp this concept though it looks more of a standard way.

My question would be, what's the best approach (not necessarily the simplest) and best practices to this solution?

Answer (score 2):

If I were you, I'd look into using a bundle that supports internationalization on routing.

The JMS Internationalization Bundle is an excellent choice for routing i18n.

https://packagist.org/packages/jms/i18n-routing-bundle

Definitely poke around the documentation and see if it's what you need in an i18n router.

Comment: I read the documentation, but still I'm not sure if using this bundle, I will be able dynamically generate routes from database? Because as far as I understand the default symfony router allows to make only static routes those that programmer, I define, yes?

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, the translation bundle can generate custom language routes based on translations you supply it.



In order to get unlimited depth, you're going to have to take make a route with locale/category/{slug} and add the name: .+ to allow you to  get category1/category2/category3/.../categoryN passed in as a parameter. It'll then be up to you to do the translation and/or load the correct controller/do the processing. JMS translation bundle (not i18n) might be able to help with the translation part.

See http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/routing/slash_in_parameter.html for info.

Comment: Oops, cc @sepikas_antanas.